# How to choose the right pronouns in elliptical clauses?

Tags: pronouns, clauses

I'm having some difficulties to understand how to use the right pronoun in a elliptical clause.

For example:

> *Ronaldo is a better football player than (I/me).*
>
> *I am a better teacher than (he/him)*

Is there anyone who can explain me clearly how to use the right pronoun in a elliptical clause?

Comment: Mr.Eee, there is already a related question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/is-it-wrong-to-say-you-are-smarter-than-me

Comment: @Carlo_R. I apologize for not searching for it firstly, which I will do in the future.

Comment: As @Carlo_R. and Mr.Eee seem to agree the duplicate question answers all concerns here, I've closed this question as a duplicate.  If in fact your question was not completely answered, or you have a reason you'd like this question reopened, please feel free to @ message me and I'll look into it.  Thanks!